# Double counting proof for skew two families theorem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am reading through [this](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/scott/Papers/twofamilies.pdf) but can't think of a way of forming a simple proof for this part.
[image: Skew Two Families Theorem]

I am specifically interested in trying to come up with a double-counting proof for Corollary 4.4 (Uniform Skew Two Families).

I have pasted an image since the text is very long.